# The best way to navigate through text fields (TextFormField) via arrow keys

Tags: flutter

Say we have a GridView holding text fields in a couple of rows/columns...
How can we jump from one text field to another with keyboard arrow keys in Desktop app?
We are talking about changing the focus easily from one field to another using left, right, down and up arrow keys something similar to Excel.

I guess we first should detect arrow pressed events and then go to specific text field depending on which arrow keys are chosen. Not sure what is the best way to jump to specific text field like Excel!?

Comment: read about FocusNodes. you could give each field focus node then by pressing the key you could change focus which will change the target field

Comment: in addition to FocusNode and RawKeyboardListener it is useful to know about focus traversal policies and groups https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FocusTraversalPolicy-class.html

Answer (score 1):

Hi by combining `FocusNode` to request the focus of the node(textfield) and `RawKeyboardListener` to listen the Key event, you can easily do it

Below i have added something like that for `3X3` table.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class ExcelScreen extends StatefulWidget {
const ExcelScreen({super.key});

 @override
 State<ExcelScreen> createState() => _ExcelScreenState();
 }

class _ExcelScreenState extends State<ExcelScreen> {
final fc = FocusNode();
FocusNode focusr1c1 = FocusNode();
FocusNode focusr1c2 = FocusNode();
FocusNode focusr1c3 = FocusNode();
FocusNode focusr2c1 = FocusNode();
FocusNode focusr2c2 = FocusNode();
FocusNode focusr2c3 = FocusNode();
FocusNode focusr3c1 = FocusNode();
FocusNode focusr3c2 = FocusNode();
FocusNode focusr3c3 = FocusNode();

var focusColumn = 0;
var focusRow = 0;
List textfocus = [];
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
textfocus = [
  [
    focusr1c1,
    focusr1c2,
    focusr1c3,
  ],
  [
    focusr2c1,
    focusr2c2,
    focusr2c3,
  ],
  [
    focusr3c1,
    focusr3c2,
    focusr3c3,
  ]
];
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
  body: RawKeyboardListener(
    focusNode: fc,
    autofocus: true,
    onKey: (event) {
      if (event.runtimeType.toString() == 'RawKeyDownEvent') {
        if (event.data.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowDown) {
          if (focusRow < 2) {
            focusRow = focusRow + 1;
          }
        }
        if (event.data.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowLeft) {
          if (focusColumn > 0) {
            focusColumn = focusColumn - 1;
          }
        }
        if (event.data.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowRight) {
          if (focusColumn < 2) {
            focusColumn = focusColumn + 1;
          }
        }
        if (event.data.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowUp) {
          if (focusRow > 0) {
            focusRow = focusRow - 1;
          }
        }
      }        
      textfocus[focusRow][focusColumn].requestFocus();
    },
    child: Column(
      children: [
        for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++)
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++)
                  Expanded(
                      child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: TextField(focusNode: textfocus[c][r]),
                  )),
              ],
            ),
          )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```